# How to populate a many-to-many relationship in ASP.NET Core model

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core app when I tried to pull the models from the database using the `Scaffold-DbContext` command, it pulled most of the tables, and added all relationships between them.

Except one table that basically have all passengers ids mapped to their registered trip ids. So I managed to find a way to inform Entity Framework to add the table like that:

```
public partial class Ticket
{
    public int PassengerId { get; set; }
    public int TripId { get; set; }
    public virtual Passenger Passenger { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual Trip Trip { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Then in the context class it has defined how the table is mapped to the class:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Ticket>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => new { e.PassengerId, e.TripId })
                .HasName("PK_Key");
            entity.ToTable("ticket");
            entity.Property(e => e.PassengerId).HasColumnName("passenger_id");
            entity.Property(e => e.TripId).HasColumnName("trip_id");
            entity.HasOne(d => d.Passenger)
                .WithMany(p => p.Tickets)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.PassengerId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Ticket_Passenger");
            entity.HasOne(d => d.Trip)
                .WithMany(p => p.Tickets)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.TripId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_Ticket_Trip");
        });
```

Now when I run the application, a single ticket object is populated with the two ids as in the actual database but for the `Trip` object and `Passenger` object it stores null instead (snipped in the JSON format):

```
{ "PassengerId": 1, "TripId": 1, "Passenger": null, "Trip": null }
```

Can someone help figure out what causes the trip and passenger not to store a reference for the object in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include related data from multiple relationships in a single query.Try :

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var ccc = _context.Ticket 
                      .Include(x => x.Passenger)
                      .Include(y => y.Trip)
                      .ToList();
    return Ok(ccc);
}
```

Read [Include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager) to know more.

Comment: thanks a lot it worked finally now